# Have to select Text from the lookup field after searching particular text like “200000882”. How can i achieve in selenium webdriver using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, robotframework

I am new to UI automation. In a webpage, there is a lookup fields, where I have to enter text `"200000882"`, based the the text I have  to select full searched text `"Environment Servicing Center (200000882)"` from the list. 
How can I achieve this in `selenium webdriver` using `python`? Tried with

```
driver.find_element_by_id(input-0).send_keys("200000882") # here entering value in the field
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(md-autocomplete-suggestions>.ng-scope).click() # Clicking on the lookup.
```

This does not work. Have included the image for reference

[image]

Comment: please post the HTML source code here

Comment: Show us `HTML` for input field. Also check if you use quotes for `find_element_by_...()` arguments

Comment: Is there any exception??? share it as well??

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you get an error? If so, what error? does it return the wrong element? If so, what element? Have you verified that `input-0` is what you think it is?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Comment: After entering the "200000882; the field, i  have to select the "Environment Servicing Center (200000882)" and clicl it.

Comment: After entering the "200000882; the field, i  have to select the "Environment Servicing Center (200000882)" and click it. Below is the  Inspecte element details

Comment: * I can not type more than 600 characters in comments. So not able to metion info properly. How can i type more?

Comment: have you inspected the element - "Environment Servicing Center (200000882)" - what is its locator?